# something about new and delete[] in c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I spent over 2 hours just debugging it and checking the error of code, but I still can not find the reason why it's crushing.
If I delete the code between `line 91` to `line 93`, the source code runs in `vs` and `vscode`, but fails in `dev-c`. The feedback of `dev-c` is `program received signal sigsegv`.
if not del, all platforms do not work?
can someone tell me the reason and the solution? thanks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class DynamicVector
{
private:
    T *array;
    unsigned mallocSize, numofItems;
    int virtualZero;

public:
    DynamicVector(int Vindex)
    {
        array = NULL;
        numofItems = 0;
        mallocSize = 0;
        virtualZero = Vindex;
    }
    DynamicVector(const DynamicVector &another)
    {
        if (mallocSize < another.numofItems)
        {
            if (array)
            {
                delete[] array;
                array = NULL;
            }
            array = new T[another.mallocSize];
        }
        virtualZero = another.virtualZero;
        mallocSize = another.mallocSize;
        numofItems = another.numofItems;
        for (int i = 0; i < another.numofItems; i++)
            *(array + i) = *(another.array + i);
    }
    ~DynamicVector()
    {
        if (array)
        {
            delete[] array;
            array = NULL;
        }
    }
    DynamicVector<T> &operator=(const DynamicVector<T> &another)
    {
        if (mallocSize < another.mallocSize)
        {
            delete[] array;
            array = NULL;
            array = new T[another.mallocSize];
        }
        virtualZero = another.virtualZero;
        mallocSize = another.mallocSize;
        numofItems = another.numofItems;
        for (int i = 0; i < another.numofItems; i++)
            *(array + i) = *(another.array + i);
        return *this;
    }
    inline void push_back(const T &n)
    {
        if (numofItems < mallocSize)
        {
            *(array + numofItems) = n;
        }
        else if (numofItems == mallocSize)
        {
            T *num = new T[numofItems + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < numofItems; i++)
                *(num + i) = *(array + i);
            if (array)
            {
                delete[] array;
                array = NULL;
            }
            array = new T[2 * mallocSize + 1];
            mallocSize = 2 * mallocSize + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < numofItems; i++)
                *(array + i) = *(num + i);
            *(array + numofItems) = n;
            delete[] num;
            num = NULL;
        }
        numofItems++;
    }
    void push_back(const DynamicVector<T> &another)
    {
        T *num = new T[numofItems + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < numofItems; i++)
            *(num + i) = *(array + i);
        if (array)
91        {
92            delete[] array;
            array = NULL;
        }
        array = new T[mallocSize + another.mallocSize];
        mallocSize = mallocSize + another.mallocSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < numofItems; i++)
            *(array + i) = *(num + i);
        delete[] num;
        num = NULL;
        for (int i = numofItems, j = 0; i < numofItems + another.numofItems; i++, j++)
            *(array + i) = *(another.array + j);
        numofItems = numofItems + another.numofItems;
    }
    T &operator[](int Vindex)
    {
        int _entry = Vindex - virtualZero;
        if (_entry < 0 || _entry >= numofItems)
        {
            cout << endl
                 << "Out Of Range";
            exit(1);
        }
        return array[_entry];
    }

    bool operator==(const DynamicVector<T> &dv) const
    {
        if (virtualZero == dv.virtualZero)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numofItems; i++)
                if (*(array + i) != *(dv.array + i))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    unsigned length() const
    {
        return numofItems;
    }
    unsigned capacity() const
    {
        return mallocSize;
    }
    int firstIndex() const
    {
        return virtualZero;
    }
};
int main()
{

    DynamicVector<int> ra(-2);
    int i, n;
    cin >> n;
    ra.push_back(-3);
    ra.push_back(-2);
    ra.push_back(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ra.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << "\n malloSize is " << ra.capacity();
    cout << "\n numofItems is " << ra.length();
    cout << "\n StartIndex is " << ra.firstIndex() << endl;
    for (i = -2; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << ra[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    DynamicVector<int> raCopy(ra);
    cout << "\n malloSize is " << raCopy.capacity();
    cout << "\n numofItems is " << raCopy.length();
    cout << "\n StartIndex is " << raCopy.firstIndex() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (i = -2; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << ++ra[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = -2; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << raCopy[i] << " ";
    }

    raCopy = ra;
    if (ra == raCopy)
        cout << "\n ra == raCopy";
    else
        cout << "\n ra != raCopy";

    ra[-2] = 100;

    if (ra == raCopy)
        cout << "\n ra == raCopy";
    else
        cout << "\n ra != raCopy";

    raCopy.push_back(ra);
    cout << endl;
    int firstI = raCopy.firstIndex();
    for (i = 0; i < raCopy.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << raCopy[i + firstI] << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you would add lines to the code, when referencing :) I am not really keen on counting 91 lines.

Comment: ok,I have do it

Comment: On the other hand, now we have to remove the numbers to run the code.

Comment: Note: Don't add line numbers that just makes it hard for us to copy and paste. Simply stick a comment at line 91 that says "The is line 91. If I remove the next three lines it sort of works."

Comment: please remove the line numbers. [Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7119/230282)

Comment: now I only set line 91-92 @phuclv

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if (array) {delete[] array; array = NULL; } array = new T[another.mallocSize];` can be written `delete [] array; array = new T[another.mallocSize];`. `delete[]` can handle null pointers, and setting `array` to `NULL` before you set it to a new value doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from uninitialized member variables in copy constructor:

```
    DynamicVector(const DynamicVector &another)
    {
        if (mallocSize < another.numofItems)
        {
            if (array)
            {
                delete[] array;
                array = NULL;
                }
            array = new T[another.mallocSize];
        }
        ...
```

Here `mallocSize` and `array` members are not initialized and contain random garbage, so the checks have could do anything. You have three senarios.

1. `mallocSize` is randomly small thus:
   `array` is not initialized and points to random memory.
   Thus line 91 will cause a sigfault when eventually called.
2. `mallocSize` is randoly large and `array` is not null.
   You call `delete` on random value thus corrupting your memory.
   Either causing a segfault or messing up memory so the line 91 does.
3. `mallocSize` is randomly large and `array` is randomly null.
   It works (1 in three chance).

Should be just

```
    DynamicVector(const DynamicVector &another)
    {
        array = new T[another.mallocSize];
        ...
```

Also, everywhere in the code you can write `array[i]` instead of `*(array + i)`, e.g. `array[i] = another.array[i]` instead of `*(array + i) = *(another.array + i)`.

PS. Once you have it working get it code reviewed.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: but even I delete the statement block,the code still cannot  run right in dev-c ,and the debug feedback is program received signal sigsegv.but it can run right in vs2019

Comment: @xioacd99 undefined behavior (which is what your code shows) means the code can do anything. A lot of development environments will set variables to nullptr/0 in debug mode which allows the code to stumble along, but when compiled in release mode these variables are no nolonger set to nullptr/0 by the compiler (as you are supposed to set them).

Comment: Deleted my answer as it said exactly the same as dewaffled.